# Add Dimension in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a solution to add an dimension to a php array. As this title is confusing Ill give you an example.
If I have the array:

```
[0] => 'xx1',
[1] => 'xx2',
[2] => 'xx3',
...
```

I want to convert it to

```
[0] => 'y' => 'xx1',
[1] => 'y' => 'xx2',
[2] => 'y' => 'xx3',
```

Is there a way to do this without using a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a way to do it without touching each element, but with `array_map` you can do it without explicitly using a loop.

```
$new_array = array_map(function($x) {
    return ['y' => $x];
}, $your_array);
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that's the best way to do it.