# PHP: Add a dimension to an array using array_map?

Tags: php, array-map

I have an array and I want to add a dimension. I want to group it using the `position` column in the array

```
$view_rows = [];

Array
(
    [row] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [position] => 1
                    [image_id] => 2809
                    [basename] => rj5ed2c90f609423.26673093.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [position] => 1
                    [image_id] => 2808
                    [basename] => rj5ed2c8eccc9c06.91700011.jpg
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [position] => 2
                    [image_id] => 2807
                    [basename] => rj5ed2c77ef32b76.96579137.jpg
                )
        )
)
```

After adding the dimension (group by `location`), it should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [position] => 1
                            [image_id] => 2809
                            [basename] => rj5ed2c90f609423.26673093.jpg
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [position] => 1
                            [image_id] => 2808
                            [basename] => rj5ed2c8eccc9c06.91700011.jpg
                        )
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [position] => 2
                            [image_id] => 2807
                            [basename] => rj5ed2c77ef32b76.96579137.jpg
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Is there a PHP function to do this? If not, I will use the good old looping method.

I did some research here ( [Add Dimension in PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923494/add-dimension-in-php-array) ), and I believe it can be achieve using `array_map`.

I've tried it, with no success (I'm close)

```
$new_array = array_map(function($x) {
    return [$x[0]['position'] => $x];
}, $view_rows);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to change the structure of the array, you can't use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), but you can use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce) to get the result you want:

```
$data['rows'] = array_reduce($data['rows'], function ($c, $a) {
    $c[$a['position']][] = $a;
    return $c;
}, array());
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [position] => 1
                            [image_id] => 2809
                            [basename] => rj5ed2c90f609423.26673093.jpg
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [position] => 1
                            [image_id] => 2808
                            [basename] => rj5ed2c8eccc9c06.91700011.jpg
                        )    
                )    
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [position] => 2
                            [image_id] => 2807
                            [basename] => rj5ed2c77ef32b76.96579137.jpg
                        )    
                )    
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jLF0l)

Comment: If I don't want to change the structure, but assign the values to a new array, can I use array_map? I've adapted your solution to do just that (assign the values to a new array), but I was just wondering if I could do that with array_map (I've try with no success)

Comment: @Marco, you can just change the assignment, use `$new_array = array_reduce(...)` instead of `$data['rows'] = array_reduce(...)`. You can't easily use `array_map` because `array_map` gives you a result with the same structure as the input.

Answer (score 1):

@Nick answer works but the same thing can be achieved using a simple foreach loop easily so everyone can understand it.

```
$result = [];
foreach($data['rows'] as $row) {
    $result[$row['position']][] = $row;
}
```